# Unable to cast nvarchar to datetime when calling SQL Server stored procedure from LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, wcf, localization

I have an application server that is connected to another server with SQL Server 2008R2. Both server's GUI is French and both had date and number formatting is in French. Also the SQL Server and the user used to execute command languages were set to French (all by default). However, I set the formatting in my WCF service to "en-GB" by putting this in the web.config:

I've included a stored procedure in my LINQ to SQL dbcontext file, and I'm passing a date parameter without converting it to string (as the ORM recognized it as date).

Things was going great  until sometime early today, where the procedure stopped executing throwing an exception saying that string can't be converted to date.

I've tracked the query with SQL Profiler, and found that it's executing the following query:

```
declare @p9 int
set @p9=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [GIS].[GetOnlineTrackingRecords] 
@CompanyId = @p0, @EntityIds = @p1, @MinDate = @p2, @MinRecordId = @p3, @TrackingType = @p4, @TrackAllEntities = @p5', N'@p0 int,@p1 varchar(8000),@p2 datetime,@p3 bigint,@p4 tinyint,@p5 bit,@RETURN_VALUE int output',
@p0=1,@p1='168',@p2='2013-10-24 16:36:28.690',@p3=NULL,@p4=1,@p5=0,@RETURN_VALUE=@p9 output 
select @p9
```

(The main issue with @p2)

The ORM method that wrap my stored procedure look like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name= "GIS.GetOnlineTrackingRecords")]
public ISingleResult<FMS2.Framework.TrackEntities.GetOnlineTrackingRecordsResult> GetOnlineTrackingRecords([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="CompanyId", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> companyId, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="EntityIds", DbType="VarChar(MAX)")] string entityIds, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="MinDate", DbType="DateTime")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> minDate, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="MinRecordId", DbType="BigInt")] System.Nullable<long> minRecordId, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="TrackingType", DbType="TinyInt")] System.Nullable<byte> trackingType, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="TrackAllEntities", DbType="Bit")] System.Nullable<bool> trackAllEntities)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), companyId, entityIds, minDate, minRecordId, trackingType, trackAllEntities);
        return ((ISingleResult<FMS2.Framework.TrackEntities.GetOnlineTrackingRecordsResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

When I tried to execute the same query in SQL Server Management Studio it failed, however it run successfully on my machine (with English language sql server). After I changed the language of the SQL Server Engine and the user default language to us_english it run successfully just fine, but only from SQL Server and it still fails with the same error message when being called from my WCF app. I've double checked that the query is being executed under user with us_english language using both sys.dm_exec_sessions and SQL Profiler. I've read that casting from 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' string to date should just work fine on any machine, but it seems not:( 
What shall I do next, considering that touching the code would be very difficult...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be passing a string like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Here's why:

```
SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-05-06');
```

This returns June 5th, not May 6th, as it is interpreted as `yyyy-dd-mm`. If you sub in your date (`'2013-10-24'`), you get an error because SQL Server doesn't know what the 24th month is.

Now, I have no idea how to do things in your ORM, but ideally you should *never* be passing a string at all, and so format shouldn't matter. You should be passing a date/time value, not a string.

When you do need to pass a string (and you may, again because I have no idea about the limitations of your ORM of choice, I just know that no ORM covers all the bases), you should always use a 100% unambiguous format. Try:

```
@p2='2013-10-24T16:36:28.690'
---------------^ that T is important
```

Let me spell out why, just for Alireza. [From this document](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html):

> If a date and a time are displayed on the same line, then always write the date in front of the time. If a date and a time value are stored together in a single data field, then ISO 8601 suggests that they should be separated by a latin capital letter T, as in 19951231T235959.

When you add the T, you remove SQL Server's ability to interpret the date in any other way. This isn't because it's a T, or even because of what ISO 8601 suggests, but because the code in SQL Server simply says, if there's a T, interpret the date as y-m-d regardless of regional, locale, dateformat or language settings.

Comment: @Alireza why do you keep trying to find reasons to edit my answer? If you have something to add, feel free to add a comment.

Comment: Your answer is good and complete and it only needs a little bit clarification on T. Maybe some reader doesn't see the comment to find out what T means.

Comment: @Alireza well your suggested edit didn't really explain the T, either. If you're going to edit other people's answers, make those edits worthwhile.

Comment: What I added was this simple informative sentence: *The T indicates the start of the time part of the datetime value.* Do you really think it didn't explain 'T'?

Comment: @Alireza not really, I think it's pretty obvious from looking at the string that the T separates the date and the time, like the space did before. That doesn't tell you "what T means," which you expressed above.

Comment: @AaronBertrand The OP does not convert to string. It's linq-to-sql doing this.

Comment: The points is that linq to sql strongly typed procedure doesn't accept anything but date, so practically, I'm not passing any string, it's a date parameter. However, the same query the profiler shows being executed, and sql fails to execute, I'm able to run using the same sql user, even with out T. so any more suggestions?

Comment: Yes, file a bug? Or stop using half-baked ORMs? Linq 2 SQL has no business passing a string in that format, and it should be fixed.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree, but what make the same query sniffed by sql profiler and being run on the same server with same user and same db success when being run from management studio but fails from .net? As I mentioned, it used to fail sometime early today until I changed the sql config. I believe, with some configuration change, I could manage to run it. Any hint could be helpful...

Comment: Well, let me make it simpler, any way to force sql server to do implicit cast to that string date (without T)? I believe it should be doable as it work on my machine, but not on the server. Please help

Comment: @Goldy what specific settings have you compared between the two servers and your machine already? What changed "sometime early today" when it suddenly started breaking? Why are mixing things like French here, en-gb there, what other conflicting locales are you trying to meld together and hope for the best?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now we have same language for sql users, default language for the sql server, and same regional settings format for windows. 
The IT manager claims to have nothing changed, but it's only a sudden failure with the application (so the developer is being pointed at)
When the SQL user language was French, the query failed to run from the SSMS, so I changed it to English, then it went fine but only from SSMS.

Comment: @AaronBertrand For en-gb, it makes sure that the datetime format should be treated the same way over all environments, however, I changed the regional settings (and browser language) to English to avoid any failure cause.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm trying to add every tiny details that could help with it, without making it too complicated :). However it's more complication (we have clustering and SQL fail over but I'm making everything identical on both boxes)